# trying to grab the top% of class grades using index

Tags: python, indexing, count, standard-deviation

I'm trying to find people and their grade average that are above the the standard deviation. My problem is that when its trying to match the name with the score, its saying " line 75, in 
    In=nameList.index(eachStudent)
ValueError: 84.0 is not in list". The number is in the list though.

```
y=statistics.stdev(scoreList)
count=0
In=0
x = int((1.282 *y ) + mean)
for eachStudent in scoreList:
    if eachStudent>x:
        count+=1
        In=nameList.index(eachStudent)
```

Comment: You are looking for the index of the score in NameList. Judging by the nomenclature, I'm assuming that no one is named "84.0" :)

Comment: Can you add both nameList and scoreList here?

Answer (score 1):

**84.0** is not in **nameList**

*Example:*

```
In [6]: x = [4,6,7]

In [7]: x.index(6)
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: x.index(8)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-67db2e8075c7> in <module>()
----> 1 x.index(8)

ValueError: 8 is not in list
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume

- nameList is a list of student names (or IDs)
- scoreList is a list of student scores in the same order as nameList

Then how about:

```
i = 0
for eachScore in scoreList:
    if eachScore > x:
        count+=1
        In.append(nameList[i])
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure that `eachStudent` is in the list `scoreList`, but are you sure it is in the list `nameList`? That is not at all clear from your code excerpt.